# My SSD Drive has been converted to a Core Storage drive and cannot be erased/reformatted?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, ssd, disk-utility, core-storage

I put an SSD drive into my macbook pro.
I should say that this drive hadn't been formatted and was a bootable drive with Yosemite OS on it, taken from another macbook pro...
I booted the system up in restore mode and began the process of restoring from a time machine back, on an external plugged in via firewire 800 caddy.
It said, "erasing drive", it asked me for a password, I wasn't sure why so typed my usual system password. I received the message, "drive could not be erased"
Since then the SSD drive has only show up in disk utility, not on deskop or in finder, and it cannot be erased in disk utility.
I gather from speaking with a few more enlightened apple people that it has been converted to a core storage drive...
I will post up a couple of helpful terminal read out pictures.
How do I get my SSD drive back??
Thanks in advance,
Chris

[image: diskutil]

[image: diskutil cs]

Comment: Yosemite + Core Storage is enough to make a grown man weep. Fixes start with 'discard everything & reformat..' not a happy procession

Answer (score 2):

You can blow away a corestorage disk partition by booting in [Single User Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573)...  then use this command:

**WARNING: THIS WILL RUIN ALL DATA ON THE DISK!**

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk0
```

After a moment you will see an error that the corestorage volume has come offline unexpectedly (that is because you have destroyed it).  You can now type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to stop ruining the disk.

Then you can boot in [Recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) (hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> upon boot) and proceed to format this disk.

Answer (score 0):

Much Better way to do this, you don't need to format at all, as the drive can be reverted.  Apparently a lot of the commands relating to this are undocumented?  I have no idea really but I had to go through the same process to get disk utilities to allow me to do anything related to partitioning.

Here
https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO109622.html is step by step to removing corestorage designation.

Maybe to late for you, but anyone else with this problem should give this a try

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please refrain from posting link-only answers.  Links may change and then the context of the questions and answer will be lost.  Here is some info on what makes a good answer: [answer].  - From Review -